# TFS: how to create a new work item type in currently using project?

Tags: tfs

I've exported "Bug" work item, changed "< WORKITEMTYPE name="Bug" >" to "< WORKITEMTYPE name="Issue" >" ... imported changes... and nothing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jusf found a solution myself: it is necessary to restart Visual Studio :)

Comment: It is enough to refresh the work items in the team explorer: right click on the work items node in team explorer and choose refresh